# @AllArgsConstructor is not working on IntelliJ Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I use **Spring**, as you see, I declared class Product and I used the **lombok** annotation to generate the **constructors**, but when I wanted to use it it gives me errors

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, probably you should add [Lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok) to IntelliJ

Comment: For me, I found that if I had updated the Lombok plugin but had not restarted the IDE, my annotations were not processed. Restarting the IDE fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. When I upgraded my Maven Lombok dependency in pom and Lombok plugin in Intellij it worked like a charm.